# Unable to restore the theme last set by user?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

App restores the theme when brought to the front from background or when screen orientation is changed but it does not work, when i change the press the middle button to see list of running background apps and clear it from there.

Here is code from my `themechanger class`:

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class ThemeChanger 
{
    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_DARKORANGE = 0;
    public final static int THEME_GREEN = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
    public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 3;

    public static void changeToTheme(ActionBarActivity activity, int theme)
    {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();

        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }


    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(ActionBarActivity activity, int theme)
    {
        switch (sTheme)
        {
        default:
        case THEME_DARKORANGE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Darkorange);
            break;
        case THEME_GREEN:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
            break;
        case THEME_BLUE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
            break;
        case THEME_LIGHT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
        }
    }
    }
```

Below is my code for storing theme values:

```
case R.id.bluetheme:
          editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE);
          editor.commit();
          ThemeChanger.changeToTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE);
          return true;
      case R.id.darkorangetheme:
          editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_DARKORANGE);
          editor.commit();
          ThemeChanger.changeToTheme(this, ThemeChanger.THEME_DARKORANGE);
          return true;
      case R.id.greentheme:
          editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_GREEN);
          editor.commit();
```

Here is my `onCreate method`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);      
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
    appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this,appliedtheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I know i need to restart activity to change my theme but if i write

```
ThemeChanger.changeToTheme(this, appliedtheme);
```

at the beginning my app goes in infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a piece of code that restarts the Activity inside `onCreate()`, then it makes perfect sense that you are getting a restart loop. Every time your Activity is created, it restarts. Modify your code as such:

```
public class ThemeChanger
{
    public final static int THEME_DARKORANGE = 0;
    public final static int THEME_GREEN = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
    public final static int THEME_LIGHT = 3;

    public static void restartActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }


    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, int newTheme)
    {
        switch (newTheme)
        {
            default:
            case THEME_DARKORANGE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Darkorange);
            break;
            case THEME_GREEN:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Green);
            break;
            case THEME_BLUE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blue);
            break;
            case THEME_LIGHT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need to use `sTheme` since the theme is already stored in SharedPrefs. I renamed your `changeToTheme()` method to `restartActivity()` so it accurately reflects its purpose.

When you save your values, you should restart your Activity using the method we modified.

```
 case R.id.bluetheme:
      editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE);
      editor.commit();
      ThemeChanger.restartActivity(this);
      return true;
  case R.id.darkorangetheme:
      editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_DARKORANGE);
      editor.commit();
      ThemeChanger.restartActivity(this);
      return true;
  case R.id.greentheme:
      editor.putInt("mytheme", ThemeChanger.THEME_GREEN);
      ThemeChanger.restartActivity(this);
      editor.commit();
      return true;
  //etc.
```

`restartActivity()` should *only* be used **here**, *never* in `onCreate()`. This means that `onCreate()` needs to use `onActivityCreateSetTheme()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
    appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this,appliedtheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //rest of code
}
```